# Multiindex Filterings of grouped data

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe where I have done a groupby.  The groupby results look like this:

[image]

As you can see this dataframe has a multilevel index ('ga:dimension3','ga:data') and a single column ('ga:sessions').

I am looking to create a dataframe with the first level of the index ('ga:dimension3') and the first date for each first level index value :

[image]

I can't figure out how to do this.

Guidance appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check here for some solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553626/show-first-10-rows-of-multi-index-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired from @ggaurav suggestion for using first(), I think that the following should do the work (df is the data you provided, after the group):

```
result=df.reset_index(1).groupby('ga:dimension3').first()
```

Comment: This seems to work (on me - I have to check it more thoroughly but looking good).  What is the purpose of `reset_index` and why `reset_index(1)`?

Comment: We need it in order to be able to regroup

Comment: Could you explain about that a bit more?  It looks like the reset changes the df back to a single index with date becoming a column.  Then the groupby  simply takes the first row in the newly grouped date / sessions for each dimension3.

Comment: Exactly. Date become a column again, but it's not the same with your original data. It's keeps the structure that was given from your first groupby

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use [first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html). As you need data based on just `'ga:dimension3'`, so you need to groupby it (or level=0)

```
df.groupby(level=0).first()
```

Without groupby, you can get the level 0 index values and delete the duplicated ones and keeping the first one.

```
df[~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep='first')]
```

Comment: I might not have worded this clearly.  I have already done the groupby (that is the first image).  I just want the first date (level=1) and corresponding value ('ga:sessions') for each 'ga:dimension3'  (level=0) value

Comment: I have updated the answer without groupby.

Comment: Did it work? I have taken a similar dataframe and it seems to work there.

Comment: Yes.  Useful and a good answer but green check goes to @ioaTzimas for a slightly cleaner sytax